# C# WPF Animate button with VisualStateManager triggered by an event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to animate a button triggered by an event (not on that button) with VisualStateManager. This is my code but it doesn't work. Please help find the issue or suggest a different method to animate the button.

In the xaml file I have the following

```xml
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding ScanningViewModel}">
    <Button Height="Auto" Margin="10" x:Name="ScanButton"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignOutlinedButton}"
            Command="{Binding ScanDocumentCommand}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="SearchAdd" Width="30" Height="30"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Text="Scanează" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>

                <VisualState Name="Default">
                    <Storyboard/>
                </VisualState>

                <VisualState x:Name="MyAnimation">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation 
                            To="Pink" 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Stop1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" 
                            Duration="0:0:2" />
                        <ColorAnimation 
                            To="Maroon" 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Stop2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" 
                            Duration="0:0:2" />
                        <ColorAnimation 
                            To="Red" 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Stop1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" 
                            BeginTime="0:0:2" Duration="0:0:2" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                        <ColorAnimation 
                            To="Blue" 
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Stop2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" 
                            BeginTime="0:0:2" Duration="0:0:2" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>

            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

In ScanningViewModel.cs:

```cs
class ScanningViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public FrameworkElement ScanButton { get; private set; }
        
    public ScanningViewModel()
    {
        ScanButton = new FrameworkElement();
    }

    private void SomeOtherCommand_Execute()
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToElementState(this.ScanButton, "MyAnimation", false);
    }
}
```

The goal is to add animation to a button triggered by an independent event (basically to guide the user through the app with visual clues).

Comment: A view model is not supposed to know about the `VisualStateManager` or a `FrameworkElement`...The `VisualStateManager` is used in controls - not view models.

Comment: One step towards the solution is that the button control is accessible by its name property in the code-behind, that is the class set in the x:Class property of the xaml. I could reference ScanButton in the code-behind class.